# return columns where dataframes differ in values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes like the df1 and df2 examples below.  I would like to compare values between the dataframes, and return the columns where the dataframes have different values in the column.  So in the example below it would return column B.  Any tips are greatly apreciated.

df1

```
A B C
1 2 3
1 1 1
```

df2

```
A B C
1 1 3
1 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparing dataframes using != or ne() return a boolean dataframe on which you can look for any True values using any(). This returns a boolean series which you can index with itself.

```
s = (df1 != df2).any()
s[s].index

Index(['B'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing rather than just paste code?

Comment: I mean you're just writing an answer without explaining what your code is doing. I dont mean plagiarism.

Answer (score 1):

In your above example using `eq`  with `all`

```
df1.eq(df2).all().loc[lambda x : ~x].index
Out[720]: Index(['B'], dtype='object')
```